# React-Native: Deep Linking with required fetch Call in HomeScreen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, deep-linking, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator

I'm new on react-native and deep linking. I have a react-native App with BottomBar and StackNavigator.
First Tab "Stöbern" with First StackScreen HomeScreen has a fetch Call in ComponentDidMount for renew the session Token und set a variable for "isLoggedIn". For now, i don't have Deep Linking. For now the Startscreen is always HomeScreen with this fetch call to renew the token and check if token is valid, then set it to "isLoggedIn".

HomeScreen is a public screen, Favorite is a member screen.

Now i try deep linking.

My linking.js:

```
const config = {
  screens: {
    Home: {
      path: 'home',
      screens:{
          Stöbern: {
             path: 'stöbern',
              screens: {
                HomeScreen: {
                  path: 'home',
                }
              }
          },
       Favoriten: {
           path: 'favorite',
            screens: {
              FavoriteScreen: {
                path: 'favorite',
              }
            }
        }
      }
```

In StackNavigator I have a check module:

```
<HomeStack.Screen name="FavoriteScreen" component={RequireAuthentication(FavoriteScreen, global.isLoggedIn)} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
```

If my App is open and try:
npx uri-scheme open demo://app/home/favorite/favorite --android
it works fine, because the variable IsLoggedIn is set and im routing to favoriteScreen.

If my App is closed/killed and try:
npx uri-scheme open demo://app/home/favorite/favorite --android
the logic dont go thru HomeScreen with fetch Call to set IsLoggedIn and deep linking goes to the Login Screen. This is wrong, because im logged in.

If I move the fetch call to check the token and set the variable in App.js it still doesn't work. Fetch call is calling, but the response is to late and I'm routing to login Screen.

My Question:
what is the best way for deep linking and a fetch call to check token and set a variable for "isLoggedIn"?

Another call for renew token in FavoriteScreen? But then it calls also for non deep linking calls.

What I want:
User clicks on a deep link for favoriteScreen -> open the App -> do a fetch call for renew token and set global.isLoggedIn to True -> go to favoriteScreen

I'm also trying to go always over the HomeScreen. But this doesn't work if the App is open, because the ComponentDidMount method is not calling in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There're  2 scenarios:

**Best-case**: the app is launched and ready and the user is authenticated and s/he can safely deep-link to any protected screen.

**Worst-case**: app recently killed or closed, it's required to re-authenticate and validate user token which is an asynchronous operation and takes a while which makes a deep-linked fallback to the login screen.

**1. Identify  navigation triggered by deep linking**

```
 // First, you may want to do the default deep link handling
    // Check if app was opened from a deep link
    const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();

    if (url != null) {
      return url;
    }


console.log(url)

 // url contain deep linking URL
```

While navigation is triggered by deep linking, you need to save `url` in a global store like Context API or Redux. `url` will be needed later after getting a new token.

**2. Determine whether the user needs to re-authenticate**

For the worst-case scenario, you will need to authenticate the user by silently validating the old token in the background or force to authenticate manually with a login form.

**3. Navigate to a deep-linked screen**

At this user has been authenticated or token validated, we need to deep-link to the user destination screen.

Early, we saved deep link `url` in global store, we need to link to  the corresponding screen. Unfortunately, `url` has a web-based routing structure which is not how React navigation routing works.

We need to convert web routing to React navigation routing. Below is a  minified routes mapping:

```
const routes map  = {
demo://app/home/favorite/favorite:"favorite",
demo://app/home/stöbern/home:"home",
}
```

With this routes map, you can use `navigation.navigate(map[url])` and simply navigate to that deep-linked.

This's my opinionated brute-force solution, fellow developers should come with a lean and better solution.